# watelineJS: One Way Association

Tags: node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I'm using the Waterline ORM (PostgresQL adapter) with SailsJS and I have two models:

1. buildings:

   ```
   {
     tableName: 'buildings',
     attributes: {
     id: {
       type: 'integer',
       primaryKey: true
     },
     BuildingName: {type: 'string'},
     BuildingBodyId:{model:'buildingbodies'}
   }
   ```
2. bodybuildings:

   ```
   {
     tableName: 'buildingbodies',
     id: {
       type: 'integer',
       primaryKey: true,
       required: true
     },
     RequiedBeInField: {type: 'integer'},
     BuildingViewState: {type: 'string'}
   };
   ```

I trying to return all buildings and use next query:

```
buildings.find({
  select:['id','BuildingName','BuildingBodyId']})
  .populate('BuildingBodyId')
```

It's return to result:

```
 {
     "BuildingBodyId":{
       "id":2,
       "createdAt":"2015-05-07T12:46:55.501Z", 
       "updatedAt":"2015-05-07T12:46:55.501Z"},
     "id":1,
     "BuildingName":"YellowTeaField"
 }
```

i.e. BuildingBodyId return without RequiedBeInField and BuildingViewState. Can anyone give me a tip on how to get these two tables with all parameters? Thanks.

Comment: i have had that problem before but I end up finding that my model did not have these values. check your database to see if they exist.also try adding requred:true in the …odel field

Comment: Thanks for answer  Evilsanta. But database has all values.

Comment: select() is unstable method.

Comment: @shoom try using required:true with these attributes in the requiredbeinfield

Comment: Evilsanta, it didn't help.